# how to create cascading dropdownlist in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

1.This is my controller:

```
using System; using System.Collections.Generic; using System.Linq;
using System.Web; using System.Web.Mvc; using
WebApplication7.Models;

namespace WebApplication7.Controllers {
    public class DefaultController : Controller
    {
        tarazouEntities db = new tarazouEntities();
        // GET: Default
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            List<Province> lstpro = new List<Province>();
            ViewBag.Province = new SelectList(db.Provinces, "Id", "Name");

            return View();
        }
        public ActionResult City(int id)
        {
            return Json(db.Cities.Where(x => x.ProvinceId == id), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

}

this is my view:

```
   @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Index"; } <br /> <div class="form-group">
        @Html.DropDownList("province", (SelectList)ViewBag.Province, " Select your Province", new { @class = "form-control",
    initilize_dropdown = "/default/City", drop = "#city" }) </div> <div
    class="form-group">
        <select class="form-control" id="city"></select> </div> @section scripts {
        <script>
            $('[initilize-dropdown]').change(function () {
                var id = $(this).val();
                var model = $(this).attr('initilize-dropdown');
                var fill_dropdown = $(this).attr('drop');
                $(fill_dropdown).empty();
                $.get(model, { 'id': id }, function (data) {
                    $.each(data, function (index, value) {
                        $(fill_dropdown).append(new Option(value.Name, value.Id));
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
 }
```

when i select province,city not open,city list is empty

Comment: You have not really explained what the issue is. What errors are you getting. But there are numerous issues with your code, and to implement cascading dropdownlists correctly, refer [this DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1bPZym)

Comment: i not get error,only i select province,city list not open and this list is empty

Comment: Are you hitting your `City()` method. Is it returning the correct results. What does `console.log(data);` return etc. You need to do some basic debugging (and study the code in the DotNetFiddle)

Comment: A different approach can be using a helper which I usually do. You can have a look at [here](https://github.com/alexanderar/Mvc.CascadeDropDown)

Answer (score 0):

On drop down change event send a ajax request to the controller action.
Retrieve and bind the data with the drop down

```
$.getJSON('action','controller',null, function (data){ 
   $.each(data, function(){
      $('#dplcities').append("<option value="+data.id+">+ data.CityName +"
       </option>")
    });
});
```